# A field of type "String" does not appear in the result (json) serialization of the vraptor controller

Tags: java, json, vraptor

A field of type "String" does not appear in the result of the serialization controller

```
result.use(Results.json()).indented().from(list).serialize();
```

Some fields appear, and another not appear when null, the field I want is to type "String" and implemented the "get" and "sets" and this always filled

PS: I am using vraptor framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using the "include":

```
result.use(Results.json()).indented().from(list)
                .include("codigoComposto").serialize();
```